# Define propType for a html tag as well as a string in Props validation

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to define proptype for a prop named `label` which receives two types of values sometimes a `string` or an html object such as `<span>`.I am trying to do it in different ways but I am failing to suppress the warnings.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `label` supplied to `TextField`
```

Currently, I have done:

```
TextField.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.OneOfType([PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object), PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
};
```

But it's not working.
I don't want to use `any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of your props is an HTML element then you should use **PropTypes.node** instead of
**PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object)**

```
Textfield.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.string]).isRequired
};
```